# Como centralizar essa imagem com Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando centralizar a imagem porém não obtive sucesso, consegui centralizar, porém não sei como colocar no meio da div

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>

    <title>Bootstrap - Alinhamento do grid</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .marcador {
        background: #fe9d9d;
        border: 1px solid #f94646;
        height: 420px;
      }
      .marcador-container {
        background: #5bf946;
        border: 1px solid #36ae26;
      }
      .borda{
        border: 1px solid blue;
      }

    </style>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

     </head>

     <body>

    <div class="container">

      <h2>Alinhamento vertical (align-items-ALINHAMENTO: start, center, end)</h2>
      <div class="row marcador align-items-center">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTN65ED_ansEu-oVmEbiRV2a06nsb1SYsWG2x8RwcJ9bUnFmcXNCw">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize na a classe mx-auto  text-center que irá centralizar na tela.
Observação: coloquei uma nova classe na imagem para que ela fique responsiva: img-responsive. Segue o código:

```
<div class="container">

  <h2>Alinhamento vertical (align-items-ALINHAMENTO: start, center, end)</h2>
  <div class="row marcador align-items-center">
    <div class="col mx-auto text-center">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTN65ED_ansEu-oVmEbiRV2a06nsb1SYsWG2x8RwcJ9bUnFmcXNCw">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Essa classe `.align-items-center` funciona no Bootstrap 4 (que tem suporte nativo ao flexbox), não no 3.

Para centralizar verticalmente no Bootstrap 3, adicione as propriedades à classe no CSS:

```
.align-items-center{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

**Veja:**

```css
.marcador {
    background: #fe9d9d;
    border: 1px solid #f94646;
    height: 420px;
  }
  .marcador-container {
    background: #5bf946;
    border: 1px solid #36ae26;
  }
  .borda{
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  
.align-items-center{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <h2>Alinhamento vertical (align-items-ALINHAMENTO: start, center, end)</h2>
  <div class="row marcador align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTN65ED_ansEu-oVmEbiRV2a06nsb1SYsWG2x8RwcJ9bUnFmcXNCw">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Esse tipo de alinhamento atualmente é feito com flexbox. Adicionei uma div entre a col e a imagem, segue código:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Alinhamento vertical (align-items-ALINHAMENTO: start, center, end)</h2>
        <div class="row marcador align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
                <div style="display: flex;width: 100%;justify-content: center;">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTN65ED_ansEu-oVmEbiRV2a06nsb1SYsWG2x8RwcJ9bUnFmcXNCw">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Se você estiver usando Bootstrap 4, o CSS que eu adicionei dá para fazer só usando as classes do flex, que você encontra aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/